# Why is the demonstration of $\frac{\sin x}{\sin\left(\frac{\pi-x}{2}\right)}=\sqrt{2-2\cos x}$ logically invalid?

Tags: geometry, algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, solution-verification

I know very little about mathematics in general. Earlier I developed what I thought was a proof that
$$\frac{\sin x}{\sin\left(\frac{\pi-x}{2}\right)}=\sqrt{2-2\cos x}$$

by showing two formulas of $x$ referring to the same length on a triangle. I inputted a few values for this, and it was found to be incorrect. I would like to know why exactly the logic in this proof is invalid.

The false demonstration:

[image]

Comment: Where does the $\sin (\frac{\pi - x}{2})$ come from? It's not in the diagram.

Comment: FYI, using the standard trig identities, $\frac{\sin x}{\sin\left(\frac{\pi-x}{2}\right)} = 2\sin(\frac{x}{2})$.

Comment: $(\pi-x)/2$ is the measure of the angles other than $x$ in the original isosceles triangle.

Answer (score 1):

This is a correct proof.  The geometric proof given by the poster makes sense if $x$ is strictly between 0 and $\pi/2$, and the identity holds for these $x$.  In fact the identity will hold at least for $0\le x\le 2\pi$, $x\ne \pi$.

To prove this in another way, since $\sin(\pi/2-x)=\cos x$, the left-hand side of the identity can be rewritten as $\sin x/\cos (x/2)$, and since by the double-angle formula for $\cos x$, we have $\cos x =\cos^2(x/2)-\sin^2(x/2)=1-2\sin^2(x/2)$, the right-hand side of the identity is $\sqrt{2-2(1-2\sin^2(x/2))}=\sqrt{4\sin^2(x/2)}=2\sin(x/2)$, assuming that $\sin(x/2)$ is nonnegative.  Then the identity reduces to the double-angle formula for $\sin x$.  (We need the assumption $0\le x\le 2\pi$ in order to have $\sin(x/2)\ge 0$.)

Comment: The identity clearly does not hold between every other consecutive even multiple of $\pi$, e.g. $[2\pi,4\pi]$. At best, you can say that you need $\pm \sqrt{2-2\cos x}$. The most fundamental issue is that $\sin(x)$ and $\sin((\pi-x)/2)$ need not share signs. [Desmos graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/eq5sgxmphm)

Comment: Yes, you need $\sin(x/2)\ge 0$, as I explained in my answer.  The OP's proof is correct though.